# Geometry nodes absolute position of points

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to determine the absolute position of points. So I created a node network that would add the object info (of the same object) with the position. The object is a parented object with rotation. But I am unable to get the correct position.

[image]

For better illustration, I added empties at the position I get for option Relative and Original in the *Object Info* node.

[image]

Comment: what about providing your blend file/try? how should we know what you made wrong if we don't know anything you did?

Comment: @Chris, good point. Sure, I will add one. Sorry, i assumed that this is such a simple query to add a node network screenshot

Comment: Object *Location* minus $(0,0,0)$ plus *Position*. Use `Self Object` as *Input* in `Object Info` (version 3.4) ...Sorry for the brevity, I'm on the road right now.

Comment: you have chosen "original" in object info, did you try to use relative?

Comment: @quellenform, noted... few weeks of excited waiting for 3.4... :)

Comment: @Chris.. i tried both... i am adding one more screenshot in which i created empties (at position i get from the spreadsheet) for both relative and original

Comment: @RMK: i don't get it. For me it looks like the viewer node is just showing the local coordinates. And with parenting...it doesn't work at all. But maybe i just don't get it ;) and that's how it supposed to work - just showing local coordinates and you have to calculate the world coordinates on your own by happy matrice-calculations ;)

Comment: @Chris, i too am confused. Author blindness, maybe :) And I am yet to become friends with Matrix calculation. But in general, I think i am doing a mistake by not considering the rotation & scale attributes from Object Info for calculating the global co-ordinates before showing in the viewer. I will try that